# Focus Added Item in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview

This seems simple but for the life of me I can't figure this out.

I have an ExpandableListView with a customized ExpandableListAdapter descended from BaseExpandableListAdapter.  When I add a new item I simply want to focus the new item.  I can't get that to work.

I tried the following, which does not work.  This is in the activity with the listview:

```
private void processNewItem(C360ItemOwner itemOwner, int pos){
    Item item = itemOwner.newItem(pos);
    expAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    expandList.requestFocus();
    if (item.getParentType() == Item.PARENT_IS_CHECKLIST) {//main level
        expandList.setSelectedGroup(pos);
    } else //Item.PARENT_IS_ITEM //sub level
        expandList.setSelectedChild(item.getParentAsItem().getPosition(), pos, true);
}
```

I tried doing it in the adapter on the getView method, which does not work:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.edit_group_item, null);
    Item group = (Item) getGroup(groupPosition);
    convertView.setTag(group);
    EditText edtParent = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtParent);
    edtParent.setTag(convertView);
    scatterItemText(edtParent);
    if (group.isNew()) {
        Toast.makeText(edtParent.getContext(), "Found Focus Item " + groupPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        edtParent.requestFocus();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

I tried setting up a couple of fields in the adapter: focusItem, a write only Item object and focusEdit, read only EditText obect.  So I assign the item and in getView, it stores the edit in a field.  I call it like this:

```
private void processNewItem(C360ItemOwner itemOwner, int pos){
    Item item = itemOwner.newItem(pos);
    expAdapter.setFocusItem(item);//<--Assign it here
    expAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    EditText edtFocus = expAdapter.getFocusEdit();
    if (edtFocus != null)
        edtFocus.requestFocus();

}
```

Then in getView of the adapter:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.edit_group_item, null);
    Item group = (Item) getGroup(groupPosition);
    convertView.setTag(group);
    EditText edtParent = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtParent);
    edtParent.setTag(convertView);
    scatterItemText(edtParent);
    if (group == focusItem) {
        Toast.makeText(edtParent.getContext(), "Found Focus Item " + groupPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        focusEdit = edtParent;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

I was very hopeful for this last method but this line:

```
EditText edtFocus = expAdapter.getFocusEdit();
```

Occurs BEFORE the getView() method runs which would assign it (so it's always null)! :-(  plz halp

EDIT: I know this would be sloppy but what if I did ran a thread to wait a few hundred milliseconds so that getView() might run and then try to get focusEdit?

Comment: you wouldn't need a thread to pause like that. Look at `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, int delay);`

Comment: "I tried the following, which does not work" why this aren't work?  dont go to Adapter getView  direction

Comment: @Tomer I'm sorry I am not understanding?  Please explain more?   Thanks to both of you.

Comment: please explain why the first scenario didn't work,  i believe the first scenario is the solution

Comment: I'm not sure, it just does not focus the correct view for some reason?  I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work, however I was able to get it to work with a handler which I will post as an answer.  Thank you so much.  When I have some time, I will look closer and try to figure out why the first didn't work and will post back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out with the help of Foamy Guy.  My hunch about waiting a bit to check for the focusEdit worked out.  I initially tried with 1000 milliseconds to give it plenty of time:

```
private void setFocus() {
    EditText edtFocus = expAdapter.getFocusEdit();
    if (edtFocus != null)
        edtFocus.requestFocus();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BLAH!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        setFocus();

    }
};

private void processNewItem(C360ItemOwner itemOwner, int pos){
    Item item = itemOwner.newItem(pos);
    if (itemOwner.getItemCount() == 1)
        checkHasItems();
    expAdapter.setFocusItem(item);
    resetListAdapter(true);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);//this works
    //handler.postDelayed(r, 10);//this works too
    //handler.postDelayed(r, 1);//this works too
    //handler.post(r);//this too!
    //r.run();//NOT this.  This fails.
}
```

Then I tried 10 milliseconds and it still worked.  Then just one millisecond and amazingly that worked too.  Foamy suggested to try to just post without the delay and indeed that works.  I finally tried to just run the runnable directly per Foamy's request but that failed.

So not sure, but this gets the job done.  Thanks for the help guys.